# Anyone have a code to convert char array to HEX ? And return back to the actual results?

Tags: c++, arduino

Anyone have a code to convert char array to HEX? And return back to the actual results?

Because when I try to use this:

```
char data[]="hello word";
Serial.print(data,HEX);
```

then will give me an overload error.

Comment: `Serial.print(data,HEX);` only accepts an integer or a char not a c-string.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this by yourself?

Comment: What is the expected resul? `68656c6c6f20776f7264`?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ hex conversion example"

Comment: Also, search the internet for "c++ arduino print hex character string".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He already has the code to convert a byte array to a hex string: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49130180

Answer (score 1):

For brute force, you could try:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data) - 1)
{
  Serial.print(static_cast<unsigned int>(data[i]), HEX);
}
```

In the above snippet, each character is casted to an integer to get the internal representation value, then output.

There may be more efficient methods, but that is left to the OP to research.