# Need to convert encrypt data to HEX to send to the SIGFOX "AT$SF"

Tags: arduino

I use AESLib library to encrypt the temperature but I face some issue when I try to send to the sigfox because is uses "AT$SF" that means is sending only in HEX. So there is any solution for convert this output to send to the sigfox ??

this is my simple code:

```
void aes128_enc_single(const uint8_t* key, void* data1);
void aes128_dec_single(const uint8_t* key, void* data1);

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
char data[] = "hello";
aes128_enc_single(key, data);
Serial.print("encrypted:");
Serial.print(data);

}
```

this is the output:

```
encrypted:⸮pᬊw⸮⸮>O⸮b⸮>⸮
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone have a code to convert char array to HEX ? And return back to the actual results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135413/anyone-have-a-code-to-convert-char-array-to-hex-and-return-back-to-the-actual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serial.print(x)` is for human-readable. To send a string in hexadecimal over serial port, use:

```
char data[] = "hello";
int i;
for (i=0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
    Serial.print(data[i], HEX);
}
```